# Page Style not working in sugarcrm 6.2

Tags: sugarcrm

I was implemented Page Style Option in the sugar 5.5 it works properly. when upgrade the system from the 5.5 to 6.2 it does not work properly

Please anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've moved these options in the User's Settings in 6.0